# Get order with parameter in method GET

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I develop an API with Symfony4 + Api platform and I create a route to retrieve the command based on a parameter that I send in GET except that when I call the route I have an error message that I can not identify:

> {
>     "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
>     "@type": "hydra:Error",
>     "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
>     "hydra:description": "Not found, because of an invalid identifier configuration",
>     "trace": [
>       {

Here is my class to which I defined a route:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\DateFilter;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"orderGET", "orderGetCollection"}},
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *         },
 *         "post"={
 *             "method"="POST",
 *             "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"orderPostCustomer"}},
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')"
 *         }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "getItem"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"orderGET", "orderGetItem"}},
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')"
 *         },
 *         "put"={
 *             "method"="PUT",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"orderPostCustomer"}},
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *         },
 *        "tracking_order"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"orderGET", "orderTracking"}},
 *             "route_name"="get_tracking_code_order",
 *             "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')",
 *             "swagger_context"={
 *                 "parameters"={
 *                      {
 *                     "idTrackingAkaz" = "string",
 *                     "in" = "path",
 *                     "required" = "true",
 *                     "type" = "string"
 *              }
 *            },
 *             "responses" ={
 *                  "201" ={
 *                      "description" = "Tracking code akaz",
 *                      "schema" = {
 *                          "type" = "object",
 *                          "required" = {
 *                              "idTrackingAkaz"
 *                          },
 *                          "properties" = {
 *                              "idTrackingAkaz" = {
 *                                  "type" = "string"
 *                              }
 *                          }
 *                      }
 *                  },
 *                  "400" = {
 *                      "description" = "Invalid input"
 *                  },
 *                  "404" = {
 *                      "description" = "resource not found"
 *                  }
 *              },
 *              "summary" = "Send tracking code",
 *              "consumes" = {
 *                      "application/json",
 *                      "text/html",
 *                },
 *              "produces" = {
 *                      "application/json"
 *              }
 *         }
 *     }
 *     }
 *  )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"idTrackingAkaz": "exact", "lastHistory.status": "exact", "customer.city": "partial", "city": "partial", "lastHistory.User": "exact"})
 * @ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"dateAdd"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderRepository")
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"orderGET", "orderDELETE", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $address1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGET", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2000, nullable=true)
     * @Groups("orderGetItem")
     */
    private $urlTracking;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $idOrderMerchant;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem"})
     */
    private $idTrackingMerchant;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"orderGET", "orderTracking"})
     */
    private $idTrackingAkaz;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderHistory", mappedBy="orderId", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups("orderGetItem")
     */
    private $orderHistories;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderHistory", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="last_history_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Groups("orderGetCollection")
     */
    private $lastHistory;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @Groups("orderGET")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $weightMerchant;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Groups("orderGetItem")
     */
    private $weightReal;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $packages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups("orderGET")
     */
    private $dateAdd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups("orderGET")
     */
    private $dateUpd;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderDetail", mappedBy="orderId", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Groups({"orderGetItem", "orderPostCustomer"})
     */
    private $orderDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups("orderGET")
     */
    private $dateStampAkaz;

    /**
     * Order constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateAdd = new \DateTime();
        $this->dateUpd = new \DateTime();
        $this->orderHistories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->orderDetails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $phone
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $address
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getAddress1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address1;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $address1
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setAddress1(string $address1): self
    {
        $this->address1 = $address1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getZipcode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $zipcode
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setZipcode(int $zipcode): self
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $city
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $country
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|int
     */
    public function getIdOrderMerchant(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idOrderMerchant;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $idOrderMerchant
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setIdOrderMerchant(int $idOrderMerchant): self
    {
        $this->idOrderMerchant = $idOrderMerchant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getUrlTracking(): ?string
    {
        return $this->urlTracking;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $urlTracking
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setUrlTracking(string $urlTracking): self
    {
        $this->urlTracking = $urlTracking;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getIdTrackingMerchant(): ?string
    {
        return $this->idTrackingMerchant;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $idTrackingMerchant
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setIdTrackingMerchant(string $idTrackingMerchant): self
    {
        $this->idTrackingMerchant = $idTrackingMerchant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getIdTrackingAkaz(): ?string
    {
        return $this->idTrackingAkaz;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $idTrackingAkaz
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setIdTrackingAkaz(string $idTrackingAkaz): self
    {
        $this->idTrackingAkaz = $idTrackingAkaz;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrderHistory[]
     */
    public function getOrderHistories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orderHistories;
    }

    /**
     * @param OrderHistory $orderHistory
     * @return Order
     */
    public function addOrderHistory(OrderHistory $orderHistory): self
    {
        if (!$this->orderHistories->contains($orderHistory)) {
            $this->orderHistories[] = $orderHistory;
            $orderHistory->setOrderId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param OrderHistory $orderHistory
     * @return Order
     */
    public function removeOrderHistory(OrderHistory $orderHistory): self
    {
        if ($this->orderHistories->contains($orderHistory)) {
            $this->orderHistories->removeElement($orderHistory);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($orderHistory->getOrderId() === $this) {
                $orderHistory->setOrderId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastHistory()
    {
        return $this->lastHistory;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastHistory
     */
    public function setLastHistory(OrderHistory $lastHistory): void
    {
        $this->lastHistory = $lastHistory;
    }

    /**
     * @return Customer|null
     */
    public function getCustomer(): ?Customer
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * @param Customer|null $customer
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCustomer(?Customer $customer): self
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getWeightMerchant(): ?int
    {
        return $this->weightMerchant;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $weightMerchant
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setWeightMerchant(int $weightMerchant): self
    {
        $this->weightMerchant = $weightMerchant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getWeightReal(): ?int
    {
        return $this->weightReal;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $weightReal
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setWeightReal(?int $weightReal): self
    {
        $this->weightReal = $weightReal;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateAdd()
    {
        return $this->dateAdd;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getDateUpd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateUpd;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTimeInterface $dateUpd
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDateUpd(\DateTimeInterface $dateUpd): self
    {
        $this->dateUpd = $dateUpd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrderDetail[]
     */
    public function getOrderDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orderDetails;
    }

    /**
     * @param OrderDetail $orderDetail
     * @return Order
     */
    public function addOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail): self
    {
        if (!$this->orderDetails->contains($orderDetail)) {
            $this->orderDetails[] = $orderDetail;
            $orderDetail->setOrderId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param OrderDetail $orderDetail
     * @return Order
     */
    public function removeOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail): self
    {
        if ($this->orderDetails->contains($orderDetail)) {
            $this->orderDetails->removeElement($orderDetail);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($orderDetail->getOrderId() === $this) {
                $orderDetail->setOrderId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPackages()
    {
        return $this->packages;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $packages
     */
    public function setPackages($packages): void
    {
        $this->packages = $packages;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstname
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname): void
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastname
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname): void
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDateStampAkaz()
    {
        return $this->dateStampAkaz;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTimeInterface $dateStampAkaz
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDateStampAkaz(\DateTimeInterface $dateStampAkaz): self
    {
        $this->dateStampAkaz = $dateStampAkaz;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea of ​​what I forgot? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I did some debugging...
In vendor/api-platform/core/src/Identifier/IdentifierConverter.php:49 the inital Exception is thrown: Resource "My\Model" has no identifiers.

My Model is configured in a yaml file. There, I added the property "id" and marked it as "identifier = true". Of course, the property as well as the setter and getter must exist.

```
resources:
  My\Model:
    properties:
      id:
        identifier: true
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and found that routes specified as `itemOperations` require the `{id}` to be in the route, otherwise it won't work. You can work around it by making it a `collectionOperations`, but it actually makes sense to operate on a given object (which is also tested for existence by API Platform).

Hope this helps :)